Are there any advantages of survival analysis over regression for prediction?
I came across survival analysis recently, and it seems quite useful for modeling the time that an event occurs and/or handling censoring. The motivating examples in the literature make sense, for example in a clinical trial we might have participants dropping out, or those who might've experienced adverse effects but the study ended prematurely.
In my application, I am modeling time-to-events with machine learning and treating it as a regression problem. However censoring isn't really an issue here, and I'm wondering whether survival analysis would provide any advantages over a standard regression approach.
To simplify the setting, suppose we have data from a widget factory. The average time until a widget fails is $\bar{Y} = 40$ days (max of 100 days), while the dataset goes back several years and there are a few million observations. So there's some right-censoring sure, but it's relatively trivial given the size of the data. We also observe widget-level covariates $X$ which affect the time of failure.
Currently I'm just modeling it as a nonparametric regression problem, that is learning the function $f : X \to Y$ which minimizes $L^2$ empirical risk/MSE. If the goal here is only prediction of the time-to-failure $Y$ with no interest in inference, would survival analysis provide any advantages over the regression approach?

When you say "there's some right-censoring sure, but it's relatively trivial given the size of the data", is that because very few widgets last 100 days or because you simply have a lot of cases where they fail before then (and a lot which survive that long)?  In the latter case, I would have thought that survival should be part of your analysis, especially if you have any information about the widgets beyond their survival time.

Ah I should clarify - unlike clinical trials where everyone gets treated at the start, here the data consists of the widget factory continuously producing widgets. Since all widgets in the sample live under 100 days, over the course of several years the data includes the full lifecycle (until failure) for several million widgets. By "right-censoring being trivial", I mean maybe we don't observe some widgets' full lifecycles for those made in the last < 100 days (suppose we collected data as of today), but it's very few cases and we can simply drop them.

In that case, it seems reasonable to restrict your analysis to widgets produced more than 100 days ago, so excluding those produced recently which have not yet failed and excluding those produced recently which have failed.

So I've dug through the literature a bit, and the answer seems to be inconclusive in terms of any theoretical advantages. However I think it's worth trying, especially if framing it as a standard regression problem isn't working well (e.g. very noisy data, model not converging, etc). Though keep in mind I still only have a very cursory understanding of the literature.
My thought process is as follows. The main advantage of survival analysis seems to be the ability to handle censoring. When censoring is not an issue, the benefit is not as clear. For example one of the most common ways to incorporate covariates is the Cox proportional hazards model. If the goal is only prediction of individual time-to-events $\hat{T}$, then it's best to do this flexibly using ML for example using neural networks in the hazard function with DeepSurv (Katzman et al. 2018). However this can't back out individual point estimates of $\hat{T}$ without some parametric restrictions on the distribution, which is not ideal for prediction. There's an extension of DeepSurv that allows for nonparametric estimation of $\hat{T}$ in Baek et al. 2021, however the proposed architecture just looks like a standard regression model with extra steps.
However there are some methods such as Random Survival Forests (Ishwaran et al 2008) that can model the survival function $S(t|X) = P(T\geq t|X)$ directly. From this, we can back out interesting quantities such as the mean $\mathbb{E}_{\hat{P}}[T|X]$, median, etc, so setting $\hat{T}$ to one of those should theoretically be equivalent to a regression under MSE, MAE, etc. In that sense, the additional model structure from survival analysis may be an advantage for prediction, though it can also be a disadvantage too, depending on the data.
